# Getting IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

why does following main method gives IndexOutOfBoundException at list.add(1, 2)?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1, 2);
    int total = list.get(0);
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add an element at index 1 when it the ArrayList is empty. It starts at 0, or just use add.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(1);
  list.add(2);
  int total = list.get(0); // <-- You even use 0 here!
  System.out.println(total);
}
```

Per the [`ArrayList#add(int index, E element)` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29),

> Throws:
>
> ```
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range 
>   (index < 0 || index > size())
> ```

When size == 0, the index 1 is out of range.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem:

```
list.add(1, 2);
```

To fix it, do this:

```
list.add(0, 2);
```

Or even simpler, this:

```
list.add(2);
```

Remember: in Java, lists an arrays start at index `0`, you'll get an error if you try to add an element at index `1` in an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

List maintains the insertion order.
We are trying to add an element at index 1, when the list is empty, that is why it results in **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0**

Quick Solutions:-

1. Add elements in the list using add() method of the Collection interface.

List list = new ArrayList();

list.add(1);

list.add(2);

2. Add elements to the list using add(int index, T t) method of the List interface.
   List list = new ArrayList();

list.add(0, 1); // Filling 0th index with value 1.

list.add(1, 2); // Filling 1th index with value 2.